# How to have irregular price filter ranges?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, price, filter, filtered-nav

If I configure manual price ranges, I can define the step, but that step is a constant for all ranges.

Is there a way to have, for example,

- USD 1 to USD 199
- USD 200 to USD 499
- USD 500 to USD 5,000

Only those filters?

Further more, the filters should be displayed even if no products match a particular filter.

Regards

Jaime